# Mysqldump is not working

Tags: database, mysql

When I issue the following command with -p option and it is not asking for pwd and exit to prompt in ssh.

```
mysqldump -u root -p mydb > backup.sql
```

Please let me know whats wrong with mysqldump command. Why it is not asking for pwd?

Comment: Make sure it's -p and not -P..

Comment: Can you give more of the context of that command line? Are you in an interactive shell or sending that command to another server remotely? There's nothing wrong with what you've got there - there must be something else that is interfering with its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
mysqldump -h <host> -u <username> --password=<pwd> <databasename> > db.sql
```

Or if oyou want really to be prompted on tty than:

```
mysqldump -h <host> -u <username> -p <dtabasename> > db.sql
```

Host is probably 127.0.0.1 in your case.